# How to output HTML from xs:value-of in XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

How can I put double `<br/>` tags in an XSLT file for a double line break?

For example, I want to display something like below:

```
Hi Jessica,

Your account is activated!
```

so between the comma and "Your" I will put two `<br/>` tags.

My code currently is:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(demessage/TEXT.1, demessage/TEXT.SPACE, demessage/TEXT.2, '&lt;br/&gt;', '&lt;br/&gt;', demessage/TEXT.3)"/>
```

Respectively, `TEXT.1 = Hi, TEXT.2 = Jessica, TEXT.3 = Your account is activated!`

In this case, I think the double line break should work however, it is still giving me one new line.

Does anyone have any ideas why the transform is behaving like this?

Comment: "*it is still giving me one new line.*" How are you testing this?

Comment: the xslt code is used to convert the text into email. I checked the result by checking the email received. Emails are HTML based

Comment: I am afraid that makes very little sense. Your actual output is `"Hi, Jessica, &lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;Your account is activated!"`. An HTML browser would display this as `Hi, Jessica, <br/><br/>Your account is activated!` with no line breaks and the actual markup being shown.

Comment: Apologies, the code is entered through a jshell window so actually the '&lt;br/&gt;' will turn into <br/> when I see the actual code in my browser. Then our application will use the xslt code to convert and construct xml data.    It is now working properly. It turns out it has nothing to do with my code but our application itself is misbehaving. Thanks everyone for the advice!

Answer (score 2):

XSLT constructs a result tree, not a text file. That means outputting element nodes is very different from outputting text; in particular, you don't construct an element by creating the markup representation of the element. You can construct elements typically by using the xsl:element instruction, or if the name of the element is known in advance, using a "literal result element" which is an instruction that looks just like the element you want to create: in this case `<br/>`. So it's simple: to output a `<br/>` element, use the `<br/>` instruction.

So you start by outputting a text node:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(demessage/TEXT.1, demessage/TEXT.SPACE, demessage/TEXT.2"/>
```

then you output two element nodes:

```
<br/><br/>
```

and then another text node:

```
<xsl:value-of select="demessage/TEXT.3"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to output a `br` element then you can't do that with a single `value-of` and `concat`, instead use `<xsl:value-of select="concat(demessage/TEXT.1, demessage/TEXT.SPACE, demessage/TEXT.2)"/><br/><br/><xsl:value-of select="demessage/TEXT.3"/>`.